# SSH client does not timeout when connection to server has been diconnected

Tags: ssh

I think there is a simple answer to this question, but everything I find online is about *preventing* SSH client connections from timing out.

In this case, the client has established a connection to the server, and remains connected. Then the connection is disrupted, say the ethernet cable is unplugged, or the router is powered off.

When this happens, the client connection is not dropped.

The ssh client connection is part of a script and the line that performs the ssh login looks like this:

`ssh -Nn script@example.com`

The .ssh/config contains the following parameters:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

When these disconnects occur, I'd like the client ssh connection to timeout, and allow the script to attempt reconnect...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was wrong about this being a simple question, since no one was able to provide an answer.

My further reading and asking led to one reply on the openssh IRC channel, around 2022-06-06. I was advised that the options:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

Often don't disconnect the client as one might expect.

The ssh_config man page:

```
ServerAliveCountMax
    Sets the number of server alive messages (see below) which 
    may be sent without ssh(1) receiving any messages back from 
    the server.  If this threshold is reached while server alive 
    messages are being sent, ssh will disconnect from the server, 
    terminating the session...

    The default value is 3.  If, for example, ServerAliveInterval 
    (see below) is set to 15 and ServerAliveCountMax is left at 
    the default, if the server becomes unresponsive, ssh will 
    disconnect after approximately 45 seconds.
```

Seems to pretty conclusively state that disconnecting on lack of server response is the intention of these parameters. However, in practice this doesn't happen in all cases. Maybe the caveat here is: "while server alive messages are being sent"?

If the application calls for a reliable client disconnect when the server becomes unresponsive, the advice was to implement an external method, separate from the ssh client login script, that monitors server responsiveness, and kills the ssh client process on timeout.